# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0007, No data is available for the requested resource

Tags: xmlhttprequest, rdp, jszip, filesaver.js

I have an app that is failing to load in IE. When I look in the console I see
The same code works in IE11 but the code not woking in RDP IE11 couldnot find out exact cause for the issue.
During save it says couldn't download zip document

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0007, No data is
>   available for the requested resource

Comment: Where you able to find a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. It was due to IE not handling deflate properly. Use gzip instead of deflate.